# choosing a website address using the input command

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I have a bit of silly question:
On the code below, I want to access a website and extract all the prices using pandas (that bit works), what i'd like to know is how to amend the target website using input (or tkinter entry.get() on a future iteration)
What I do know works:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
a = input("Enter drug: ")
url = 'https://bnf.nice.org.uk/medicinal-forms/amoxicillin.html'
page = requests.get(url)
table = pd.read_html(page.text)
print(len(table))
#print(table)
df = pd.concat(table)
print(df)
df.to_excel('prices.xlsx')
```

What I'd like to do but I do know it does not work:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
a = input("Enter drug: ")
url = 'https://bnf.nice.org.uk/medicinal-forms/'a'.html'
page = requests.get(url)
table = pd.read_html(page.text)
print(len(table))
#print(table)
df = pd.concat(table)
print(df)
df.to_excel('prices.xlsx')
```

Any help, hints would be great, thanks.

Comment: Use string formatting or concatenation.

Comment: `f'https://bnf.nice.org.uk/medicinal-forms/{a}.html'`

Comment: @barmar, post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: This is really too basic.